# how to pass random encrypted data in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

i have number which is in encrypted form and I have to pass this encrypted value to the API from Jmeter. I know I can use Random Variable in Jmeter to generate random values. But how to generate random encrypted value?

PS: I am new to Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

This encrypted value can be either session id or authentication token.

You need to extract these values from request which is generating your random encrypted value and add it as header in required request.

Hope this helps you...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping @Poorvaja.. but actually I have to pass the number in encrypted form in body data of HTTP request and I cannot pass value like how you have showed.This thing will help me in some other concepts for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the encryption algorithm, for example you have [__MD5()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#MD5supfont-color-gray-size-1-since-0-4-2-font-sup) and [__base64Encode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) functions available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/).

You can install these custom functions using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

For other encryption algorithms you can use [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) language to write the encryption code.